# Developing an interactive book for Windows-Runtime

Tags: c#, animation, farseer-physics-engine, storyboard

My three year old loves playing with the interactive books on our iPad, and I love playing with code and I love my Surface RT...

So I thought I'd try and make a basic animated book using WinRT, I've spent some time reading about [animations](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Foundation-Silverlight-3-Animation-ebook/dp/B00ACC29B4/ref=sr_1_1_bnp_1_kin?ie=UTF8&qid=1359316617&sr=8-1)
(granted the book isn't WinRT based), and thought I'd try and use the [Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard.aspx) approach rather than rolling any kind
of bespoke animation framework.

That was until I saw the [Faresee Physics Engine](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/), and the [Physics XAML Helper](http://physicshelperxaml.codeplex.com/).

I've played around with some of the more basic examples, and it seems pretty good - very easy in-fact.

My issue is when I start thinking about stringing together animations that can react to input,
the Farsee and Physics XAML Helper blows my mind a little.

As a proof of concept I was thinking about getting a character to walk from a path (in the top right),
and while moving closer (getting larger) walk to the front at the center.

Then, based on some kind of decision, via an input, walk either back to the right, or up to the left.
Both are back into the distance (getting smaller) as if walking away.

The character should have basic humoid movement, athough slightly cartoon-like - swinging arms, moving head and legs.
Also, it would be nice to have the ability for the character model to swap images when it walks back up the path.

My question (finally!), is do you think that it's better to use the built in Storyboarding features of WinRT, with it's
animations - primarily using easing and descrete key frames to create each animation 'scene'. Or, use something like
Farsee and the Physics XAML Helper to create the scene using real word objects and physics?

Are there any examples, samples, tutorials etc of creating anything similar?

Thanks,
Kieron

Comment: Using physics and realistic models for such an application would be overkill. Keep it simple! Pre-drawn key frames (spritesheets) are good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real physics don't get good animations like the ones needed for a interactive book for children. My advice, use a tool like Flash or similar to create the animations and then load the files from your Book program.

A must see in animations is the [12 principles of animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_basic_principles_of_animation)